# Format of date / time values in database tables

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I am reading a csv file with date fields of formatted `mm/dd/yyyy`. I expected the same kind of format from a Postgres table after the import, but I see `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`.

The date fields in my table are defined as `timestamp without time zone` data type.
How do I maintain the same format of data? I am using PostgreSQL 9.3.

Comment: Postgresql stores dates as `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` handle formatting in the application or query.

Comment: @engineersmnky: that's not correct. Timestamps are stored without any formatting in Postgres (the storage is an 8 byte integer, so it can't be a string of 20 characters).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name PostgreSQL stores time stamps both date and time with or without time zones in an 8 byte integer. When displaying this data it is formatted as above.per ISO 8601  Dates are actually 4 bytes and displayed as yyyy-mm-dd although generally all rails "dates" are actually stored as timestamps

Comment: @engineersmnky: so we do agree that Postgres does not store a timestamp as `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name agreed stores was the wrong word but for ease of understanding he will always receive that format as a view or response to a query unless additional formatting is applied.

Answer (score 3):

Postgresql only stores the value, it doesn't store formatting (which would waste space).

You can use the to_char function in your query if you like to get the output formatted in a special way. Details are in the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/functions-formatting.html).